# Firebase Google Login return 403 require OAuth consent

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, google-oauth

follow the official tutorial and got this page for all code just copy paste and in the firebase console tell if on iOS or web doesn't require any config 
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to `Projects Overview` -> `General` -> on `Public settings`, find Support Email and make sure you set your email there, you should stop receiving this error after you set it.